# Changing main form

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I made a project in Visual Studio 2010 (winforms). I made a new Form and I want this new Form to be main Form of the program. How can I change it?

Comment: it's in the properties of the project

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the project properties of the startup project, set the Startup Form to your new form.

[image]

Answer (score 12):

Open up your `Program.cs` file in your visual studio project and just change the reference to your new form.

Comment: Thx it helped me :)

Answer (score 7):

Look in your `program.cs` file and change it where it says where it says `Application.Run(new OldForm());`