# How to swap out the main form?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I want to change out my previous main form for a new one.

According to this: [Changing main form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6433056/changing-main-form)

I can go to my project's properties and set "Startup form" there. However, in VS 2010 I see a rather different set of options and properties on the Application tab. For example, instead of "Starup form" I have "Startup object" (which happens to be set, apparently be default, to "(Not set)" although it has .Program in the list.

So...how can I change my main form (and, tangentially, should I set my Startup object to be my project rather than leaving it not set)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C# doesn't have "Startup form" - that's a Visual Basic thing.

In C# open your Program.cs file and look for the "new MainForm()" constructor call (it will look something like this:

```
Application.Run( new MainForm() );
```

Swap that out for the form you want to use, e.g.:

```
Application.Run( new MyNewForm() );
```

Comment: Thanks; I have never used VB, so maybe it's a Delphi thing. But actually, to me, it's six of one and half a dozen of the other / you say to-MAY-to, I say to-MAH-to*, as the first form that displays is, to me, the Main form or Startup form, and making that swappable from the properties sheet.applications tab seems eminently sensible to me. *Actually, I say to-MAY-to, and I don't know how you say it and have never heard anybody pronounce it that other (rather lame) way (to-MAH-to) except when using the above phrase.

Comment: Different philosophy: VB and Delphi both provide an environment and framework for applications, C# does not and is less prescriptive in this regard which makes it more flexible. For example, what if you want to have two forms appear at startup? C# makes that easier.

Comment: Interesting, although I don't recollect ever seeing two forms at startup. If I needed that, my first thought would be to instantiate the second one from the first one's Load event.